# Get selected text with itext

Tags: java, pdf, itext, vaadin

I am using itext in vaadin Framework to read a pdf document and I want to get the text that I select (blue highlight normal selection) in this pdf with itext.

After many search I haven't been able to found out this specific way of selection.

Comment: iText doesn't render a PDF file to the screen. iText can create a PDF document and you can open that document in a PDF viewer (Adobe Reader, pdf.js, Chrome PDF viewer,...), but at that point, iText no longer plays a role. **You can not select text (blue highlight) in iText.** That's simply impossible: iText is not a PDF viewer. Therefore I think this question is not about iText®.

Answer (score 0):

The text selection process is done by Operating system itself.
This is OS specific task. You have to use windows/Linux (based on the OS) specific functions in Java to achieve your target.